# How to record a video using React-Native on web?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-vision-camera

I am trying to record a 10 sec video through the webcam on a web app using React-Native.
I found a couple of libraries for Android and iOS like react-native-camera, but these don't seem to work similarly on the web.

This is strange, because I'm coding in React Native specifically for its cross-platform support.

Any guidance on how I can record in a web app is highly appreciated.

If it's not possible, guidance on how to take a series of consecutive pictures through the webcam will also be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried [expo-camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) ?